# Debugged program crashes after resuming execution

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am debugging a remote program using Eclipse(gdb) and a gdbserver. I am attaching my Eclipse to the already running program. Then it stops the execution at the position my breakpoint is. This all works well. I can see the content of the variables. Great. But if I then want to resume the execution via e.g. Resume or Step Over, the program gives me a segmentation fault. Do you have any ideas why a segmentation fault can happen if a debugger comes in ?

The program uses multiple threads.
The last gdb traces output is following. Here a SIGILL is throwed.

```
    064,490 59-exec-next --thread 7 1
    064,629 59^running
    064,629 *running,thread-id="7"
    064,629 (gdb) 
    064,685 *stopped,reason="signal-received",signal-name="SIGILL",signal-meaning="Illegal instruction",\
    frame={addr="0x000000000044c2df",func="func_func",args=[{name="this",value="0x4053b8"}],fil\
    e="src/funcs.c",fullname="/home/local/wolle/src/funcs.c",line="100"\
    },thread-id="7",stopped-threads="all",core="1"
```

Comment: Seriously, try setting a breakpoint somewhere else. Nobody is going to be able to help based on your description of the problem.

Comment: okay, it seems like that the problem is a pid namespace problem. You need to be in the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

okay, it seems like that the problem is a pid namespace problem. You need to be in the correct namespace. – mr.wolle